# Printing all possible combinations using recursion

Tags: python, recursion

I'm trying to write a Python program that outputs all possible strings formed by using
the characters `c, a, t, d, o` and `g` exactly once using recursion only.

so far I've got this:

```
i = ['c', 'a', 't', 'd', 'o', 'g']

counter = 0
def func(i):

    global counter

    i[counter], i[counter+1] = i[counter+1], i[counter]
    print(i)

    if counter != 5:
        counter += 1
        return func(i)

func(i)
```

EDIT: 
sorry for being "impolite", but I just copy-pasted the exercise from the book. This is just a pure text from the book.

Comment: @paul rooney Permutations != combinations

Comment: @PaulRooney You' shouldn't have. You were right.

Comment: @m.wasowski And what are the "combinations"? Name at least two.

Comment: Tip: algorithm for generating combinations is recursive, it might be easier for you to write it first using recursion. It is not very practical solution in Python,though, but later you might easily rewrite it into iterations.

Comment: Order matters so this is a permutations question right.

Comment: I see you _need _ to use recursion,so start with all combinations of one-element list as the base case, and then think how to construct from this combinations of 2-el list etc.

Comment: @paul,@stefan my bad, sorry

Comment: At least I learned (or re-learned) the difference today.

Comment: @PaulRooney Also, there is only one "combination" that uses every letter exactly once, so that would be rather boring :-P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No idea what you're trying with yours or how to fix that, sorry. But here's one way to do it.

```
def words(letters, word=''):
    letters or print(word)
    for letter in letters:
        words(letters - {letter}, word + letter)

words(set('catdog'))
```

The `letters or print(word)` is just a shortcut for `if not letters: print(word)`. Python's `or` evaluates the left part, and if that's "truthy", it returns that, otherwise returns the right part. So here, if `letters` is truthy, i.e., there are letters left to use, then that's it. Otherwise, print.

It's a bit tricky, maybe, but I find it fairly natural. You've maybe heard the phrase "Stop or I'll shoot!", right? If the person stops, then that's it. Otherwise, they'll be shot. Same thing in Python, pretty much.

Comment: Thank you very much. Could you explain step by step how your code works? I'm confused with this line `letters or print(word)`.

Comment: I've added an explanation to the answer.

Comment: I still don't understand the code. In you `for` statement after 1st iteration it returns a function `words({'a', 't', 'd', 'o', 'g'}, word='c')`.It does not print `word` because `letters = True`. But then, after all iterations we get `words({}, word = 'catdog')`, which prints this word because `letters = False`. How is this function able to start 2nd series of iteration and print characters in random order? and why does it get random?

Comment: It's random because I use a set to hold the remaining letters, which is useful here. Don't know why you're wondering about 2nd series. After the first, the recursive calls return and others are made.

Comment: eh, still don't understand. Ok, I probably will be able to understand it when I get more experience. Thank you anyway

Comment: Yeah, I get the feeling you should maybe try easier recursive functions first. This one is not hard, but there are easier ones.

Answer (score 0):

This page has some good methods (I'm assuming you can't use the itertools module, so just ignore those posts).

[StackOverflow Question 104420](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/104420/how-to-generate-all-permutations-of-a-list-in-python)